# How to pass multiple argments with process.startInfo.Arguments

Tags: c#, arrays, console, arguments

I have this peace of code here:

```
void Main(string[] args) {
   string[] ARRAY = new string[2];
   ARRAY[0] = "1";
   ARRAY[1] = "2";
   
   Process process = new Process();
   process.startInfo.FileName = @"PATH"; //runs itself
   process.startInfo.Arguments = ARRAY;
   process.Start();
}
```

I need the program to pass whole array to next instance itsself (it is able to receive), but i keep getting that it requires string. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`process.startInfo.Arguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-6.0) is of type `string` and you are trying to pass array of string to it.

```
public string Arguments { get; set; }
```

Instead of passing entire array, you have to convert it to the string first and then assign it to `process.startInfo.Arguments`

```
...
process.startInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", ARRAY);
```

---

Your final code will look like,

```
void Main(string[] args) {
   string[] ARRAY = new string[2];
   ARRAY[0] = "1";
   ARRAY[1] = "2";
   
   Process process = new Process();
   process.startInfo.FileName = @"PATH"; //runs itself
   process.startInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", ARRAY);
   process.Start();            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is what you need
}
```

---

For more details: [string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

Comment: When this worked for me, I was like a little kid when you show it a magic trick

Answer (score 0):

startInfo.Arguments = "-sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer"

Comment: Please learn to use the formatting tools available in the editor, and please include explanations rather than just code.